# Batch file set command isn't working in if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the below `set` prompt won't work when it is in the `if` statement:

```
@echo off

REM :askdeletecsvs
if exist *.csv (
    echo Warning! All files in the scripts folder that have the "CSV" extension will be deleted!
    echo Answering "n" will continue the script without deleting the CSVs.
    set /p ASKDELETE=Delete CSVs? (y/n): 
REM     
REM     if ( /i %ASKDELETE% equ "y" goto :deletecsvs )
REM     if ( /i %ASKDELETE% equ "n" goto :runscripts )
REM     goto :askdeletecsvs
)
```

When I run the batch file as it is above the cmd window opens and then shuts quickly. If I move the `set` line outside of the `if` statement then the prompt shows as expected. (There *are* csvs in the folder the bat file is running from)

What am I missing?

Comment: Read about [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with you had used a closing parenthesis which was prematurely ending your opening `If` parenthesis.

I'd suggest reversing the thinking:

```bat
If Not Exist *.csv GoTo runscripts

Echo Warning!
Echo All files in the scripts folder that have the "CSV" extension will be deleted!
Echo Answering "N" will continue the script without deleting the CSVs.
Choice /M "Delete CSVs" 
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo runscripts

:deletecsvs
Del /F /Q /A "PathTo\scripts\*.csv"
GoTo :EOF

:runscripts
```

*You can change `GoTo :EOF` to a relevant valid label as necessary or remove it if you want to continue on to `:runscripts`. You can also replace `PathTo\scripts\` with `%~dp0` if the batch file is running from the scripts directory, or remove `PathTo\scripts\` if the current directory holds those files. (note that the current directory and batch file path may not necessarily be the same)*

Comment: Had to look up some of the switches, but I see what's happening - with the exception of the `If ErrorLevel` line. I found info on `errorlevel` (at https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html), but only for 0 and 1. What is 2 and what would trigger it?

Comment: To find out about a commands basic usage, enter the command at the command prompt followed by `/?`, e.g. `Choice /?`, `Del /?`, `If /?` etc.

Comment: I entered `errorlevel /?` and the response was "'errorlevel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch flie."

Comment: Oh. Sorry for my daftness. Thanks.

Comment: That's fine, `ErrorLevel` isn't a command, its the result of a command, so the output you received was technically correct, and hence the reason it didn't work for you!