# SET /p crashing batch file process

Tags: batch-file, variables

In a batch file I'm getting information from the user for later database work.

I first ask if the user is using Windows Auth and then depending on the answer, I ask for username & password, or set a variable and continue on.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out why one of the `SET /p` lines is causing the batch file to crash, when another `SET /p` line isn't.

Here's my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


CHOICE /M "Will you be using Windows Authentication to connect to the database?"

ECHO ERRORLEVEL: %ERRORLEVEL%
@PAUSE

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    ECHO ERRORLEVEL should be 2: %ERRORLEVEL%
    @PAUSE
    SET _USINGWINAUTH=FALSE

    SET /p _USERNAME=User name: 
    REM SET /p _PASSWORD=Password (NOTE: Password will be displayed as you type): 
) ELSE (
    ECHO ERRORLEVEL should be 1: %ERRORLEVEL%
    @PAUSE
    SET _USINGWINAUTH=TRUE
)


ECHO.
ECHO _USINGWINAUTH: %_USINGWINAUTH%
ECHO _USERNAME: %_USERNAME%
ECHO _PASSWORD: %_PASSWORD%

@PAUSE
```

As is, with the second `SET /p` commented out, regardless if you answer `Y` or `N` the script runs fine.

But if the second `SET /p` line is not commented, regardless of what the answer is, the script instantly closes right after hitting a key at the pause before the `ECHO ERRORLEVEL`.

I just don't see why that's happening!

Comment: When using closing parentheses inside  a (code block) in any text the code block  ends prematurely if not escaped with a caret `^)`

Comment: Right before I saw this, I took out the NOTE part and it ran, so I see what I'm doing wrong there. Thanks again, @LotPings!

Comment: Put the prompt string in between quotation marks; the problem is the `)` which is recognised by the command interpreter as the closing one for the `if ErrorLevel 2 (` condition...

Comment: @aschipfl Is there any way to echo the parenthesis within the IF block? I can change it per your suggestion - just a matter of curiosity... I found that three carats allows the paren to display, but one carat is displayed before the closing paren - two carats still crashes the script

Comment: Too late to edit my last comment. I found that a single carat before the closing paren that I want to display works.

Comment: @marky, I believe you were given two options to echo the `)`.  You either surround your `SET` command in quotes or you escape the `)` with a `^`.  How many more options do you want.

Comment: @Squashman - yup, sorry - I missed LotPings' answer and typed out my comments before I saw it.

Comment: You were also warned about the closing parentheses in one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628803/batch-file-set-command-isnt-working-in-if-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per last time, whilst using a caret works, it would be better if you were to rework the logic.

One example:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /M "Will you be using Windows Authentication to connect to the database"
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" SET "_USINGWINAUTH=TRUE" & GOTO NEXT    
SET "_USINGWINAUTH=FALSE"
SET /P "_USERNAME=User Name: "
SET /P "_PASSWORD=Password (will be displayed as you type): "

:NEXT
ECHO(
SET _USINGWINAUTH
SET _USERNAME 2>NUL
SET _PASSWORD 2>NUL
PAUSE
```